# ASP.NET webform cannot get the second select html control

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog

I cannot get the second select control called "Select2".
But I can get the first select control "Select1".
Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

```
    function ShowModalDialog(myData) {
        gmyData = myData;

        var x = document.getElementById("Select1");
        var y = document.getElementById("Select2");
            }

    protected void btnPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyItem> myList = new List<MyItem>();
        myList.Add(new MyItem("t1", "v1"));
        myList.Add(new MyItem("t2", "v2"));
        myList.Add(new MyItem("t3", "v3"));

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);

        string szJS = "ShowModalDialog(" + output + ");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key1", szJS, true);
    }

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
                This is a simple popup
                <br />

                <select id="Select1" onchange="mySelectFunction1();" />
                <select id="Select2" onchange="mySelectFunction2();" />

            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" OnClick="btnPopup_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the problem in `ShowModalDialog`? If so, can we see the rest of that function?

Comment: The problem is at `ShowModalDialog`. [Here](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=FBEB6373D9321A7F&resid=FBEB6373D9321A7F%21649499&authkey=AOAuMj0V5MfjNVs) is my complete source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` at the top of the aspx page.
This sets the Client ID to be the same as the ID of the server control.
[MSDN - Control.ClientIDMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Since his `select` elements don't have the `runat="server"` attribute, they are not server controls. Therefore, their ID should not be mangled and the `ClientIDMode` property should not apply to them.

Comment: True, good point. I'm kind of new to posting on SO. Should I delete me answer?

Comment: It's up to you. You could keep it, so that other users who thought about the same solution could see our discussion and/or comment on it. Also, other people could come here looking for a solution to similar problems, and your suggestion may apply to their case.